# Locate the code/process creating entries

Tags: process-builder

We use a Salesforce application created by a third party, which we have now taken over the management of.

We have a Process Builder process that creates a set of records in a different object when an Opportunity is marked as "Closed-Won". We've also had some of these records created in this object on a few rare occasions *before* the "Closed-Won" stage was reached (we know this as we record the Stage history).

We've searched through all the Process Builder entries - nothing relevant appears to be triggered from our Opportunity that could have done this.

Is there any way to search through Salesforce Setup, e.g. *"Find all [things] that reference/create object type X"* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to Object Manager -> Custom object ->Fields and Relationships.
Once you click on one of the fields, on the top right you should be able to see a button called 'Where is this used?', which should tell you if a process builder/Flow/Apex is using that field and populating the values.

Comment: Many thanks for the help..